# Rotate mapbox compass with device current status

Tags: android, mapbox, compass

I have enabled compass in mapbox using `mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);` but I want to move compass icon direction with device direction. I mean when a user changes his direction, compass in mapbox map moves. Like Google Maps app.
Currently compass responds to map rotation not user.
How can I do that ?

Comment: If you're using the `LocationComponent`, you can set the camera mode to `CameraMode.TRACKING_COMPASS` or `CameraMode.NONE_COMPASS`, which will rotate the camera in the direction the user is facing. You can also provide your own `CompassEngine` with `LocationComponent#setCompassEngine`.

Comment: Thank you, I have set that to just TRACKING...